# How add a new Key/Value pair to a JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have a JS function which should add a key-value pair to a JSON Object.

When the key already exists then it should append the value to the existing key (nested JSON Objects).
Otherwise, it should create the key with the value.

At the moment, sometimes it returns true for the '.hasOwnProperty(key)' method, even when this key doesn't exist.

```
var myObject= '{}';

function add(key,value){

   if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        var length = Object.keys(myObject[key]).length;

       var obj =JSON.parse(myObject);
        obj[key] = {};
        obj[key][length]= value;
        myObject= JSON.stringify(obj); 
    }
    else{ 
        var obj =JSON.parse(myObject);
        obj[key] = {};
        obj[key]["0"] = value;
        myObject= JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
}
```

How the JSON Object should like

```
myObject = {
    "50": {
         "0": "value1",
         "1": "value2", 
         },
    "51": {
         "0": "value3",
         "1": "value4", 
         }
};
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and ouput?

Comment: please stop adding answers showing how to add a new entry to object  for this question its clearly he got a problem with the usage of his add function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for existence of a key in an object with the "in" operator

```js
    var car = {make: 'Honda', model: 'Accord', year: 1998};
    
    console.log(car);
    console.log('make in car: ', 'make' in car);
    // expected output: true
    
    delete car.make;
    console.log('removed make');
    console.log(car);
    
    console.log('add make in again, if not there');
    if ('make' in car === false) {
      car.make = 'Suzuki';
    }
    
    console.log('car.make : ', car.make);
    // expected output: "Suzuki"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const addEntry = (myObject, key, value) => ({ ...myObject, [key]: value });

console.log(addEntry({}, "hi", 5)); // { "hi": 5 }
console.log(addEntry({ key: 5 }, "hi", 5)); // { "key": 5, "hi": 5 }
console.log(addEntry({ key: 5 }, "key", 2)); // { "key": 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```js
var myObject= {};

function add(key,value){

   myObject.hasOwnProperty(key) ?  myObject[key][Object.keys(myObject[key]).length]= value : myObject[key] = {"0": value};
   
}

add(50, "Hello")
add(50, "World")
add(51, "World")

console.log(myObject)
```